# remove group and permissions options sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

i've made to diferent forms for my backend app, one for users of group **admins** and another for users of group **clients**, becuase **clients** have additional info that **admins** don't, i already set the groups by default in the code, as they are no required to create an user, i want to remove this options from the form, i already tried in the generator.yml

```
form:
    class: sfGuardClientUserForm
    display:
      "User":                   [first_name, last_name, email_address, username, password, password_again]
      "Permissions and groups": [is_active]
```

but the options keep showing, so, i tried unsetting the widget in the form class

```
unset($this['groups_list']);
```

but i get an exception saying the widget doesn't exist

how can i remove this options?? group list and permissions, they are not required anyway

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably copied generator.yml from plugins to your app directory and editing the latter. This is a known issue. Symfony will still read generator.yml in plugin's dir. So you have to either delete the file in the plugin's dir (the easiest way), or read here for some more involved solutions: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/43279/

Comment: thank you men, you save me from smash my head with the keyboard, so, if i want to overwrite the schema.yml, need to do the same??

Comment: No, I think it works fine with schema. Just copy it and extend if you need to. If you move your schema.yml then generated model files will be located in lib/model/doctrine/sf* rathen than lib/model/doctrine/pluginName/sf* (same for forms and filters). And if you have a lot of plugins - it is not convenient. However you shouldn't really touch plugins' schema. You'd rather extend it with relation class (like sfGuardUserProfile extends sfGuardUser), but it can be a pain in the ass. The state of the art is to you Doctirne Inheritance.